# Displaying default file icons in Ubuntu

Tags: python, qt, ubuntu, pyqt, qlistview

I'm using the following code to display the files inside the current directory:

```
   self.treeView = QtGui.QListView(self.centralwidget)
   self.treeView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 60, 440, 461))
   self.treeView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("treeView"))
   self.fileSystemModel = QtGui.QFileSystemModel(self.treeView)
   self.fileSystemModel.setReadOnly(True)
   self.root = self.fileSystemModel.setRootPath('.')
   self.treeView.setModel(self.fileSystemModel)
   self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.root)
```

The result of the code in Windows is something like,
[image: in windows]

in which the default file icons is showed properly.

But in Ubuntu, all files are showed as an empty file:
[image: in ubuntu]

Why results are different from Windows's?
What should I write extra code for Ubuntu? Thanks for helps